# Use MythBuntu As A Streaming Server

Tags: streaming, mythbuntu

I have been using Serviio (a windows based DLNA server) to stream media to my other mobile devices (music & movies).  Yesterday, I stumbled upon MythBuntu and was wondering if this would be a possibility to replace my Windows Serviio installation.  I installed MythBuntu however, I do not see a way (and I could be missing it) of customizing it so that I could use it as a streaming server.

Not only would I want to use it to stream on my local network, I would also like to stream to the web.  Does someone have a good tutorial on how to set this up using MythBuntu?

Answer (score 0):

MythBuntu is a front-end/back-end PVR. I beleive what you are looking for is called PLEX. It is a media server and streaming linux based program.